# Scanner returns wrong int value

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Java newbie here.

I made a function to simply return an int given by user through Scanner.
The goal is to avoid an error if the user does not type an integer, notify them and let them retry.

It works fine if the value is an integer on the first try, but if I type a char (get an error, function "restart") then the function will return the "default" zero.
Tried different things but I definitly  don't get the logic here.

Here is the code :

```
  //Initialize the Scanner earlier
  public static Scanner keyBoardRead = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static int intEntry()
  {
  int entry;
  keyBoardRead = new Scanner(System.in);
  if (keyBoardRead.hasNextInt() == true)
    {
    entry = keyBoardRead.nextInt();
    System.out.println("entry variable = "+entry);
    // Here the correct entry prints but doesn't seem to return
    return entry;
    }
  else
   {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry.\n");
    intEntry();
   }
  return 0;
  }
```

Sample output :

```
z
Invalid entry.

2
entry variable = 2

// Function exits and output = 0 (?!)
```

Thanks for your help and please criticize my code :)

Comment: The `0` output is coming from the `return 0;` statement at the end of your method. In your `else` block you probably wanted to `return intEntry();` instead (which then lets you delete `return 0;` because it's unnecessary). As an aside, while it's OK to use recursive calls for this sort of thing while you're learning, you definitely don't want to use recursion for data input on a real program. See if you can figure out how to do the retry using a loop instead.

Comment: The program flows till the end of the method and you told the method to return 0 no matter what, hence you always get 0. If you want to return the entered value, you should return entry,

Comment: Change `intEntry();` to `return intEntry();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reworked your code a bit as there were a few flaws with it:

```
public static Scanner keyBoardRead = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int intEntry()
{
    int entry;
    if (keyBoardRead.hasNextInt())
    {
        entry = keyBoardRead.nextInt();
        System.out.println("entry variable = "+entry);
        // Here the correct entry prints but doesn't seem to return
        return entry;
    }
    keyBoardRead.next();
    System.out.println("Invalid entry.\n");
    return intEntry();
}
```

Here are the changes explained below:

- You do not need to redeclare `new Scanner(System.in)` with every call
  to the method, you state you initially declare it as a class field,
  so it should be accessible from inside the method each time.
- Your `else` statement in general is completely unnecessary because you have a `return` in your `if`.  If your `if` is executed, it will never enter the code afterward anyway.
- You need to return the value from `intEntry()` with `return intEntry()` as currently you are just discarding the `return` value and simply returning `0` unconditionally if `else` is executed even a single time.
- You need to use `keyBoardRead.next()` if an invalid entry is entered in order to move to the next value and discard the previously entered result.  You can also use `keyBoardRead.nextLine()` instead if you wish to discard the entire line instead.
- Using `== true` on a boolean value is redundant as you can simply check the boolean directly, so `if (keyBoardRead.hasNextInt())` instead of `if (keyBoardRead.hasNextInt() == true)`.  Credit to @Joop Eggen for catching it.

**Example Run:**

```
hi
Invalid entry.

wrong
Invalid entry.

entries
Invalid entry.

55
entry variable = 55
```

Note: You have a lot of blank space in the output because you are use `println` and *also* using `\n` in the print so it will move to the next line *twice*.

Also you could easily create a variant to this solution that utilizes a `while` loop instead of recursion, which is probably a better way to do it so you cannot possibly run into a stack overflow (and is typically easier to read), but I kept the recursion in to keep it similar to your solution.

Comment: Fine with a `next()`. Tip: `== true` is not needed too. The OP seems to want a loop when the entry fails.

Comment: @Joop Eggen Ah yes didn't notice he was using `== true`, will change that.  Also it does currently loop with recursion like he was attempting to do, do you mean he wants a standard loop instead?

Comment: as you already rewrote it in tail recursion, I thought it to be easy & nice to turn it in a loop.

Comment: IMHO there is no need to use recursion for a simple input program. Every wrong input will invoke the method which create an overhead in the stack. Just use a loop for re-prompt for entry.

Comment: @user3437460 I agree it shouldn't use recursion, however the OP chose to use recursion, and Im fixing _his_ implementation instead of writing my own.

Comment: @Nexevis Thanks a lot ! Redeclaring the Scanner already seemed odd. The idea was to display the "command capture" but now I guess that the line "entry = keyBoardRead.nextInt();" does it by itself ?
I also guess that without the line "keyBoardRead.next();" the function would turn into a loophole ?
And finally regarding the return statement, I don't unterstand why it didn't work with my first crappy version.
Shouldn't the "return entry;" nested in the if statement exit the function and just return the entry variable regardless the final return line ?

Comment: @Pablo When it comes to `return`, just think about what happens when you go through your code the first time without worrying about the recursion.  It goes into the `else`, completes that, then will _always_ `return 0`.  It didn't matter what your recursion did at all because you weren't _using_ the value from it.  Also yeah you need the `next` because if you know the next value is not what you want, you still need to read it to move past it, or else you will just keep looking at the same value over and over again.

Comment: @user3437460 Thanks for your comment. Indeed, something like "while (!keyBoardRead.hasNextInt())" would be better right ? What would be the technical issue with the recursion ? Is it that each time the input is invalid, the function would be called recursively hence, creating ultimately a stack overflow ? (RAM overload ?)

Comment: @Pablo Without the `!` is fine too, it just depends on the case and you still need a `next` no matter what to move forward, `hasNextInt()` is just looking ahead but not actually doing anything with it.  Also yes if the input is invalid enough times the program would stack overflow and exit out.  Recursion is also just typically harder to read, and is more useful for logic that uses tree-like structures.

Comment: @Nexevis Oh ok I see it now. My recursion does return the correct value but returns it within the original function which then, return the final line, zero. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Nexevis Yes I got the 'next' now. To phrase it simply it clears the Scanner inputs to avoid, in my case, a loophole.

Comment: @Pablo I think it'd be easier to think about it almost like a cursor that is moving.  Every time you use any form of `next` whether `next` or `nextInt`, you move the position forward 1 time.  `nextInt` was correctly moving the position 1 time every time a value is read, but in the `else` `nextInt` is not there, so the cursor would stay at the same position indefinitely.  Whether you choose to _keep_ the value from that position or not is just whether you do a `String str = keyboard.next();` or just don't save the value with `keyboard.next();` by not setting it back to a variable.

Comment: @Nexevis Ok then I should see the Scanner as a big line of chars and ints typed by the user, and Scanner methods are here to move the cursor within this line, `next` moving it 1 time and `nextInt` jumping to the next int right ? But I don't really unterstand what command create the 'invite' for the user to type. Is it just the fact that the 'cursor' is at the end of the line ? BTW I refactored my code and made it into a short and neat while loop ;) Thanks

Comment: Seems like `.hasNextInt()` prompts the user to type, and I don't understand why.

Comment: @Pablo Because it is waiting to _look_ at the next value to decide to be `true` or `false`, but it doesn't actually do anything with the value and doesn't move to the next one either.  I recommend reading up on some of the documentation to get a better understanding.

Comment: @Nexevis Right I'll read a bit of documentation before bed :) Thanks for your help, I got to make my code work, refactored it and understood my mistakes.